# Have rTorrent to move .torrent files

Tags: linux, rtorrent

I am running rTorrent 0.9.2 and have configured it to move completed torrents to a different folder with this configuration line:

`system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.set_directory=~/done/;execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,~/done/"`

This is working fine, but I would like it to also move the .torrent file that it creates (from a magnet link into the session directory) into this done directory with the same name as the torrent and a .torrent extension. I tried adding another cp command, but I can not seem to figure out which variable ($d.get_hash did not work) stores the torrent's hash (which is what the .torrent files are named in the session directory). Is there a way to do this with rTorrent, if so how?

Answer (score -1):

See [here](http://community.rutorrent.org/Recipe/Move%20.torrent%20file%20after%20loading%20it,%20including%20ones%20loaded%20from%20watch%20directories), the verbs are there (how to get a basename, for example), you just have to exchange the subjects (i.e. filename commands you intend to use).